# Slow execution of USQL

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have created a simple script to score between two strings. Please find the USQL and BackEnd .net Code below

**CN_Matcher.usql:**

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY master.FuzzyString;

@searchlog =
        EXTRACT ID int,
                Input_CN string,
                Output_CN string
        FROM "/CN_Matcher/Input/sample.txt"
        USING Extractors.Tsv();

@CleansCheck =
    SELECT ID,Input_CN, Output_CN, CN_Validator.trial.cleanser(Input_CN) AS Input_CN_Cleansed,
           CN_Validator.trial.cleanser(Output_CN) AS Output_CN_Cleansed
    FROM @searchlog;

@CheckData= SELECT ID,Input_CN, Output_CN, Input_CN_Cleansed, Output_CN_Cleansed,
                   CN_Validator.trial.Hamming(Input_CN_Cleansed, Output_CN_Cleansed) AS HammingScore,
                   CN_Validator.trial.LevinstienDistance(Input_CN_Cleansed, Output_CN_Cleansed) AS LevinstienDistance,
                   FuzzyString.ComparisonMetrics.JaroWinklerDistance(Input_CN_Cleansed, Output_CN_Cleansed) AS JaroWinklerDistance
                                       FROM @CleansCheck;

OUTPUT @CheckData
    TO "/CN_Matcher/CN_Full_Run.txt"
    USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

**CN_Matcher.usql.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Analytics.Types.Sql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CN_Validator
{
    public static class trial
    {

        public static string cleanser(string val)
        {
            List<string> wordsToRemove = "l.p. registered pc bldg pllc lp. l.c. div. national l p l.l.c international r. limited school azioni joint co-op corporation corp., (corp) inc., societa company llp liability l.l.l.p llc bancorporation manufacturing c dst (inc) jv ltd. llc. technology ltd., s.a. mfg rllp incorporated per venture l.l.p c. p.l.l.c l.p.. p. partnership corp co-operative s.p.a tech schl bancorp association lllp n r ltd inc. l.l.p. p.c. co district int intl assn. sa inc l.p co, co. division lc intl. lp professional corp. a l. l.l.c. building r.l.l.p co.,".Split(' ').ToList();
            return string.Join(" ", val.ToLower().Split(' ').Except(wordsToRemove));
        }

        public static int Hamming(string source, string target)
        {   
            int distance = 0;
            if (source.Length == target.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!source[i].Equals(target[i]))
                    {
                        distance++;
                    }
                }
                return distance;
            }
            else { return 99999; }
        }

        public static int LevinstienDistance(string source, string target)
        {
            int n = source.Length;
            int m = target.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1]; // matrix
            int cost; // cost
            // Step 1
            if (n == 0) return m;
            if (m == 0) return n;
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) ;
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++) ;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    cost = (target.Substring(j - 1, 1) == source.Substring(i - 1, 1) ? 0 : 1);
                    d[i, j] = System.Math.Min(System.Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                              d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            return d[n, m];
        }

    }
}
```

I have ran a sample batch with 100 inputs and set parallelism as 1  and priority as 1000. **The job completed in 1.6 minutes**.

I wanted to test the same job with 1000 inputs and set parallelism as 1 and priority as 1000 and as per my calculation **since it took 1.6 minutes for 100 inputs I thought it would take around 20 minutes for 1000 inputs but it was running for more than 50 minutes and I did not see any progress**.

So I added another 100 input job and tested it ran same as previous time. So **I thought of increasing the parallelism and increased it to 3 and ran again it did not complete even after 1 hour.**

JOB_ID=07c0850d-0770-4430-a288-5cddcfc26699

The main issue is I am not able to see any progress or status.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Is there anyway to use constructor in USQL?. Since if I am able to do that I will not need to do the same cleansing steps again and again.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the file set syntax to specify the 1000 files? Unfortunately the current default implementation of file sets is not scaling well and the compilation (preparation) phase is going to take a long time (as does the execution). We currently have a better implementation in preview. Can you please send me a mail to **usql at Microsoft dot com** and I will tell you how you can try out the preview implementation.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Hi Michael it is not 1000 of files it is one file with 1000s of input. I will mail you. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at a more set-based way of doing this.  For example, rather than holding the words to remove in a code-behind file, hold them in a U-SQL table so it's easy to add to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.wordsToRemove
(
    word string,

    INDEX cdx_wordsToRemvoe CLUSTERED (word ASC) 
    DISTRIBUTED BY HASH (word)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.wordsToRemove ( word )
SELECT word
FROM (
VALUES
    ( "l.p." ),
    ( "registered" ),
    ( "pc" ),
    ( "bldg" ),
    ( "pllc" ),
    ( "lp." ),
    ( "l.c." ),
    ( "div." ),
    ( "national" ),
    ( "l" ),
    ( "p" ),
    ( "l.l.c" ),
    ( "international" ),
    ( "r." ),
    ( "limited" ),
    ( "school" ),
    ( "azioni" ),
    ( "joint" ),
    ( "co-op" ),
    ( "corporation" ),
    ( "corp.," ),
    ( "(corp)" ),
    ( "inc.," ),
    ( "societa" ),
    ( "company" ),
    ( "llp" ),
    ( "liability" ),
    ( "l.l.l.p" ),
    ( "llc" ),
    ( "bancorporation" ),
    ( "manufacturing" ),
    ( "c" ),
    ( "dst" ),
    ( "(inc)" ),
    ( "jv" ),
    ( "ltd." ),
    ( "llc." ),
    ( "technology" ),
    ( "ltd.," ),
    ( "s.a." ),
    ( "mfg" ),
    ( "rllp" ),
    ( "incorporated" ),
    ( "per" ),
    ( "venture" ),
    ( "l.l.p" ),
    ( "c." ),
    ( "p.l.l.c" ),
    ( "l.p.." ),
    ( "p." ),
    ( "partnership" ),
    ( "corp" ),
    ( "co-operative" ),
    ( "s.p.a" ),
    ( "tech" ),
    ( "schl" ),
    ( "bancorp" ),
    ( "association" ),
    ( "lllp" ),
    ( "n" ),
    ( "r" ),
    ( "ltd" ),
    ( "inc." ),
    ( "l.l.p." ),
    ( "p.c." ),
    ( "co" ),
    ( "district" ),
    ( "int" ),
    ( "intl" ),
    ( "assn." ),
    ( "sa" ),
    ( "inc" ),
    ( "l.p" ),
    ( "co," ),
    ( "co." ),
    ( "division" ),
    ( "lc" ),
    ( "intl." ),
    ( "lp" ),
    ( "professional" ),
    ( "corp." ),
    ( "a" ),
    ( "l." ),
    ( "l.l.c." ),
    ( "building" ),
    ( "r.l.l.p" ),
    ( "co.," )
) AS words(word);
```

Then to do the comparison, I split the original phrase up, removed the words we don't want then put the phrase back together again, something like this:

```
//DECLARE @inputFile string = "input/input.csv"; // 500 companies, Standard & Poor 500 companies from wikipedia
DECLARE @inputFile string = "input/input2.csv"; // 850,000 companies, part 1 of extract from Companies House


@searchlog =
    EXTRACT id int,
            Input_CN string,
            Output_CN string
    FROM @inputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent : true);
    //USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);


// Split the input string to remove unwanted words
@Input_CN =
    SELECT id,
           new SQL.ARRAY<string>(Input_CN.Split(' ')) AS splitWords
    FROM @searchlog;


@Output_CN =
    SELECT id,
           new SQL.ARRAY<string>(Output_CN.Split(' ')) AS splitWords
    FROM @searchlog;


// Remove unwanted words from input string
@Input_CN =
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT o.id,
               x.splitWord.ToLower() AS splitWord
        FROM @Input_CN AS o
             CROSS APPLY
                 EXPLODE(splitWords) AS x(splitWord)
    ) AS y    
    ANTISEMIJOIN
        dbo.wordsToRemove AS w
    ON y.splitWord == w.word;

// Remove unwanted words from output string
@Output_CN =
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT o.id,
               x.splitWord.ToLower() AS splitWord
        FROM @Output_CN AS o
             CROSS APPLY
                 EXPLODE(splitWords) AS x(splitWord)
    ) AS y
    ANTISEMIJOIN
        dbo.wordsToRemove AS w
    ON y.splitWord == w.word;




// Put the input string back together again
@Input_CN =
    SELECT id,
           String.Join( " ", ARRAY_AGG (splitWord) ) AS Input_CN_Cleansed
    FROM @Input_CN
    GROUP BY id;


@Output_CN =
    SELECT id,
           String.Join( " ", ARRAY_AGG (splitWord) ) AS Output_CN_Cleansed
    FROM @Output_CN
    GROUP BY id;



@output =
    SELECT i.id,
           i.Input_CN_Cleansed,
           o.Output_CN_Cleansed,
           CN_Validator.trial.Hamming(i.Input_CN_Cleansed, o.Output_CN_Cleansed) AS HammingScore,
           CN_Validator.trial.LevinstienDistance(i.Input_CN_Cleansed, o.Output_CN_Cleansed) AS LevinstienDistance
    FROM @Input_CN AS i
         INNER JOIN
             @Output_CN AS o
         ON i.id == o.id;



OUTPUT @output
    TO "/output/output.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv();
```

I found performance was similar, but possibly the design is more maintainable.  My code was running in only a few minutes anyway with 850+k records, not the 50+ minutes, so maybe there was another issue.  NB I was missing the FuzzyString library so didn't include that in my test - it could explain the difference.

If you get an update on this from Microsoft, please post back to this thread, even mark it as the answer if you like.

Comment: If I get a fix on this issue I will surely post it here. Thanks for the code revamp. Since it is not advisable to normalize on SQL I thought of doing it in .net end but your code looks for maintainable and it looks like you are using the full power of USQL.